# Show that it is not possible to have a triangle whose median lengths have a certain relationship with side length.

Tags: geometry

> Show that it is not possible to have a triangle with sides $a,b,c$ whose medians have length $\frac{2a}{3},\frac{2b}{3},\frac{4c}{5}$.
> [Source ISI entrance exam sample questions](https://www.isical.ac.in/%7Eadmission/IsiAdmission2017/PreviousQuestion/BStat-BMath-UGA-2016.pdf)

I could solve it as follows

It is well known that in a triangle with sides of lengths $a,b,c$ and medians $m_a,m_b,m_c$ respectively then the following identity holds true.

$m_a^{2}+m_b^{2}+m_c^{2}=\frac{3(a^2+b^2+c^2)}{4}$

Evaluating this we get $275(a^2+b^2)+99c^2=0$ which is obviously not true. Hence, proved. But I want some variety in the technique. I want to prove this with manipulation and not with some identity. Please help!

Comment: Any ideas after seven years perhaps?

Comment: Well...you could use manipulation to re-derive the identity. As stated, I think the question is too vague to have a satisfactory answer.

Answer (score 1):

HINT:

Use [this](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Median_%28geometry%29#Formulas_involving_the_medians.27_lengths) to find the lengths of the sides.

We know for valid triangle, the sum of length of any two sides $>$ the other

Comment: -The solution I used is the effect of the solution you have recommended. I have specifically said in the question that I do not want to use any identity rather some manipulation or any elegant ideas to solve it.